# Using Bayes to Find Basketball Player's True Shooting % Talent Level

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference, conditional-probability

"Suppose you know that a basketball player’s true talent level is either a 20% shooting percentage or a 30% shooting percentage. At the beginning of the season, there is a 50% chance he is in each group. The player then makes ten shots in a row. What is the probability that he is in each group now?"

I'm almost certain that this is a Bayes problem, but I'm thinking I may be setting things up wrong. In order to find the probability that they player is a 30% shooter given this start (P(30% Shooter|10/10 start)), I've set up the formula as seen below. This should account for the probability of the player making 10 consecutive shots to start the season given that they're a 30% shooter, and the probability given a 20% shooter.

[image]

However, this results in a probability of approximately 98.3% which seems like an awfully large jump in probability from 50% given only a 10 shot sample size to start the season. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've set this up correctly.

The prior is 0.5, regardless of being a 20% or 30% shooter.

The likelihood of shooting 10 shots in a row is $p^{10}$, where $p$ is the probability of success.

Your setup of Bayes' Rule is correct as well, so I would consider this correct.

Consider the question phrased another way.  I tell you that someone just made 10/10 shots and present to you two players identical in every way except their probability of making a shot.  The one has a 20% chance of making a single shot, the other a 30% chance.  I ask you to guess who made the series of shots.  Your answer should, logically, be the player who has the higher chance of making the basket.  All else equal (and all else really is equal, including the prior), the only thing which could reasonably explain the successes is the difference in probability of success.  Bayes' rule just puts a number to that.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! Your explanation really helped me make sense of the output I was seeing!